# Ant Migration: How to deploy 'System Administrator' aka Admin.profile

Tags: deployment, ant

I'm trying to migrate from one sandbox to a dev org.

An issue I'm currently having is that the field level permissions are not enabled for the System Administrator. (This org is only going to be used by myself, the sys admin)

I don't want to have to go through every object and set field level permissions.

On the original sandbox org the System Administrator has the permissions set correctly. Migration is performed using an unmanaged package. When I go into the package and select Add > Profile Settings I only see the custom profiles that I have created.

Reading around I need Admin.profile (which represents 'System Administrator'). How can I add this to the package?

Alternatively, is there a quick and easy way to set a lot of permissions for the System Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar question([What is the best way to deploy profiles in Salesforce? (especially system admin)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin)) but basically you should be able to add the following:

  Admin
  Profile

Comment: Yes I think I read that. Using that method, I have to retrieve and deploy using a package.xml. I've had no end of trouble trying to get this to work, so my preferred means (indeed only successful so far) is to use an unmanaged package within a Sandbox. I can see no way to add the Admin profile to this package. The duplicate question does not describe a means to add the Admin profile to an unmanaged package.