# Salesforce Data Migration

Tags: jitterbit

I need to push data from one salesforce org to another salesforce org. I have faced a problem while doing this. I used Jitterbit Harmony to migrate data between orgs. I downloaded and installed Jitterbit and created operations on it(Query and Upsert operations), but I can not migrate Profiles and Roles it gives that error "Profiles and Roles can not be inserted"?

Comment: Relevant: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin

Comment: you may read some usefull info in this topic http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155669/data-migration-from-one-production-org-to-another/159311#159311