# Data Migration from one production org to another

Tags: data, migration, data-migration

how do I migration data from one live org to another? We have a requirement to move data from objects which include account, contact opportunities, related activities and a bunch of custom objects. Below are some of the ways that I have come through..

1. Good old data loader
2. Informatica pluggin
3. Write a webservice in the destination org to pull in data from the source org.
4. Any other?

Which approach should I choose for this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently in the midst of this for an org of `Account-Contact-Case-CaseComment-Task` (a thankless task)

I'm planning on a specific runningUser + Data Loader + triggers as you can do several things

- Preserve the system audit fields like `CreatedDate` and `LastModifiedDate`
- Is partial success-enabled with a builtin retry file in the `errorXXXXX.csv` file
- Use triggers to automatically handle the cross-referencing you will need to add a child record to a previously loaded parent record without having to do Excel VLOOKUPs and the like. Can even handle hierarchies like `Account.ParentId` in most cases if the input is sorted by ascending ID (recommend only if you have sparse use of hierarchies - otherwise multiple passes on the object are required).
- Assign default OwnerIds where the incoming ownerId is not an active user anymore

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may try service called [Data2CRM.Migration](https://www.data2crm.com/migration/crm/salesforce-migration-service/). I think it can handle the migration data from one live org to another.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this product?

Comment: Hi, Adrian, no, I haven't) should I?

Comment: It's just that if you have one, you should disclose it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the data migration from 1 live org to another org is through `Salesforce2Salesforce connection` if the **Object Mapping is same** in both the destination and source org.

For e.g. If you want to migrate all the Accounts from 1 SF Org to another SF Org then you need to follow the below process.

1. Connection between Source and Destination org i.e. `PartnerNetworkConnection` should be created
2. `Publish and subscribe` the Account Object with field mapping in Source and destination org.
3. Write a batch class that inserts the `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` object so that all the Accounts are shared from Source to Destination.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Import2. We offer automated data migrations and can support custom objects as well. You can see how this will work with your own data with a free sample import here: https://www.import2.com/salesforce/from/salesforce

*I manage the customer experience for Import2*