# Need Package.xml for profile Deployment

Tags: deployment, ant, package.xml

Requirement: I am trying to Deploy Profiles.
I have made changes in;

1. Object Permissions
2. User permissions
3. Enabled Apex Class
4. Visual-force pages
5. Custom App setting
6. Connected App Access

What will be the **package.xml** for this.
Currently i have included porfiles in package.xml ,is this fine.
Please provide me sample Package.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Refer following documents.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm

You extract meta data belongs to the profile you need and your extracted file contains information for object settings, app settings, Apex and VF access.

**Updated :**
Here's a good explanation

[What is the best way to deploy profiles in Salesforce? (especially system admin)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin)