# Is it a must to have the source profile in target organisation prior to deployment

Tags: deployment, security, permissions, change-set, custom-profile

I deployed number of profiles to a new sandbox environment via a `change-set`, but what I can see is, all of the profiles I added to the `change-set` are NOT deployed properly, (`most of the profiles are missing`)

I doubt that, Do I need to have the same profile created in the target organization in order to migrate the profiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profiles are not deployable via changesets (Not available):

[Components Available in Changesets](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en)

Deploying a changes with profiles only sets the permissions related tot he items in the changeset and the profiles included.

See this discussion for more information on best practices:

[What is the best way to deploy profiles in Salesforce? (especially system admin)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin)

Answer (score 0):

**Shameless Plug:**  DreamFactory's SnapShot tool allows you to migrate profiles on their own.  You can migrate the full profile, or even just a partial profile.  In the screen shot below, the arrows point to one full profile and then just the field permissions and tab visibility for two other profiles.

SnapShot also allows you to edit your profiles.  Beginning with a back up, you can change settings on field permissions, object permissions, etc. then push those back into the source org or into a new destination.
[image]