# Deploying Profiles from one sandbox to another sandbox using ANT Tool or any other tools

Tags: deployment

I have 5 profiles in my test sandbox. Now i am planning to move these profiles to another sandbox. What is the best tool to deploy these profile. I seen lot of people don't deploy profiles using deployment process, they do it in post deployments.

If i do in post deployment it will take lot of time to configure manually everything. Please suggest me the safe way to deploy the profiles!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to migrate the permissions assigned to a profile from one Sandbox to another is to use Change Sets.

You can create a change set (Setup - Outbound Change Sets) with the new fields and other metadata you are wanting to move the permissions of as components, then associate the profiles you want to have the same the permissions of the metadata included migrated to the other Sandbox.

Then when you deploy the change set in your new Sandbox, the permissions of the components migrates for the associated profiles.