# System Administrator profile does not have rights to some new custom fields

Tags: deployment, custom-field, profile, system

We recently added many new custom fields to custom objects within our package.  When I deployed the new objects from Eclipse to a target org (for the purpose of packaging) I noticed that the System Administrator profile did not have access to the new custom fields.

Is there an automatic way to force the System Administrator profile to get rights (view, modify) to all new fields?  The System Administrator profile has gotten rights to hundreds of custom fields in the past, so I'm assuming this is a SFDC bug, or configuration glitch, rather than a known and understood feature of the system.

I don't want to introduce a special Permission Set for this purpose, because that was never needed for other fields, and the process of adding a permission set would inconvenience hundreds of production users.

Please explain how to guarantee that the System Administrator profile gets view and modify rights to new fields that are deployed from Eclipse to a target org.

Answer (score 3):

The System Administrator profile needs to be included in the deployment along with the custom fields and objects included. If it is not it will not automatically have access to the new fields created by the deployment.

In the short term you can either manually change the System Administrator profile in the target Org to give access to the fields or else redo the deployment including the System Administrator profile.

You can also depending on the tool you are using include just the specific permissions for these fields rather than the complete profile.

This [previous question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin) may be helpful.

Comment: When you say "...needs to be inlucded in the deployment", do you mean the actual ".profile" XML file, or do you mean just a reference to it in the package.XML?   I'm concerned here, because so many other fields did get permissions within that profile, without any change to what's being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what caught me off guard is this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_special_behavior.htm

> Custom Fields
>       Starting in API version 30.0, when deploying a new custom field, the default values for the editable and readable fields in profile
>   field permissions are false. To override the default values, include
>   field permissions for the new field in your profiles.

Comment: To clarify, other deployments to that Org had been done with a different instance of Eclipse, running v29.