# Deploying Profile with new class access using ANT

Tags: profile, ant, package

I need to deploy a new class with profile access. Is it fine to include only that class in the profile metadata while deploying and it wont override the existing access or Do we need to consider all the apex class which profile is having in the metadata.

Also, it wont override the object and field access if we deploy the apex class access only using the profile

Comment: Also, see my answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/19068/2984), basically says the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it fine to include only that class in the profile metadata while deploying and it wont override the existing access

That is correct. Other Apex classes permissioned by this profile will be unaffected if not explicitly permissioned in what you deploy.

> Also, it wont override the object and field access if we deploy the apex class access only using the profile

Correct. Other aspects of the profile will be unaffected unless you include them in your deployment.