# Deployin Profiles in Salesforce

Tags: deployment, profile, change-set

Since we can't deploy only profiles in a change set and that it requires at least one component with that profile, I've been wondering if when deploying the change set are all profile permissions going to be changed as in the new version of the profile deployed, or only permissions related to that specific component in the change set? And what consideraions should we take when deploying profiles?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Take a look at [What is the best way to deploy profiles in Salesforce? (especially system admin)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin) and don't forgot to use the search feature before asking possible duplicated questions.

Answer (score 0):

All metadata (example - object, fields, apex classes, VF pages, Record Types etc) will be impacted **only if you have added them.**

All permissions (general permissions, administrative permissions, session setting, login IP ranges) **will be deployed if there is at least one component in changeset.**

Also, a detailed discussion is here: [What is the best way to deploy profiles in Salesforce? (especially system admin)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-profiles-in-salesforce-especially-system-admin)